# How to combine the values in two lists Python

Tags: python

I have two lists:
Names = [John, Marc, Alex]
Surnames = [Stuart, Smith, Jones]

I would like to get the next list: [John-Stuart, Marc-Smith, Alex-Jones]
How can I get it?

Comment: `[f'{i}-{j}' for i in zip(Names, Surnames)]`

Comment: `list(map('-'.join, (zip(Names, Surnames))))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use zip()

```
names = [John, Marc, Alex]
surnames = [Stuart, Smith, Jones]

fullnames = [f"{name}-{surname}" for name, surname in zip(names, surnames)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use zip() function. You can use range() function as well. Using zip() function, @drum has already given the answer. I'll give using range() function. Explaination: both the list have same length so use for loop ranging from 0 to length of any list. And then add the elements of both the lists having same index and update any of the list. Your code:

```
Names = ["John", "Marc", "Alex"]
Surnames = ["Stuart", "Smith", "Jones"]
for i in range(len(Names)):
    Names[i]=Names[i]+"-"+Surnames[i]
print(Names)
```